# Уполномоченные обоих сторон

Tags: склонение, род, собирательные-числительные, историческая-грамматика

В опубликованном Секретном дополнительном протоколе к знаменитому Договору о ненападении такое написание допускается трижды. Может быть тогда, в августе 1939 года, правило теперешнего времени не действовало?

https://rg.ru/2019/08/22/rodina-pakt-molotova-ribbentropa.html

Comment: Мне кажется, что заголовок стоит заключить в кавычки. И добавить метку "числительные".

Comment: Спасибо. Пусть будет не в кавычках, в память о II томе («[обо́е]. Первая часть сложных прил. в знач.относящийся к обоим, заключающий в себе и то и другое и т. п, напр.: обоеполый, обоесторонний»).  Обоесторонний то же, что двухсторонний, — не двесторонний же.

Answer (score 1):

В орфографическом словаре (проф. Д. Н. Ушаков, **1938**; печатный вариант):
о́ба, обо́их, обо́им, обо́ими; *ж. р.* **о́бе, обе́их, обе́им, обе́ими.**
[Второй том [толкового словаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%A3%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) под редакцией Д. Н. Ушакова (с буквой "О") тоже был издан в 1938 году.]

Вот что обнаружилось в [мирном договоре между Россией и Эстонией](http://www.skylaser.ee/buh_help/obzory/Tartu%20rahuleping%20Eesti%20ja%20Venemaa.htm) (2 февраля 1920 года, Юрьев).

Статья 3. *Проведение государственной границы между **обоими** договаривающимися сторонами и установка пограничных знаков производятся особой смешанной пограничной комиссией с одинаковым числом членов от **обеих** сторон* (в одном предложении использованы обе формы).
Статья 20. *В удостоверение сего уполномоченные **обоих** сторон собственноручно подписали настоящий мирный договор и скрепили его своими печатями*.

[В учебно-методическом пособии М. В. Коротковой ([Россия и Прибалтика в XX веке](http://www.lib.unn.ru/students/src/20th_century.pdf)) в этом же договоре (стр. 16) формы приведены правильные (обеими, обеих), также как и в секретном дополнительном протоколе (стр. 84).]

Мне кажется, что приблизительно в это время и было установлено правило склонения собирательного числительного **обе** (обе́их, обе́им, обе́ими), которым мы пользуемся до сих пор.
А вот информация об изменениях в языке в ТО время доходила "до мест" не сразу (ведь получить ее тогда можно было только из *напечатанных* словарей).
Думаю, что в этот "переходный период" составители секретного протокола просто ещё не владели новыми данными (всего год прошел после издания словаря; кстати, тираж — 3000 тыс.).